# iOS How to cancel a UIView animation

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uiviewanimation

I reset a constraint and do animation (`self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`) delay 3 seconds ,In some cases I want to remove the animation , what shall I do, I have tried `self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()` but not working

this is my animation code

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 3, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.messageViewLeftConstraint.constant = 36
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: { (finished) -> Void in           
})
```

this is cancel code I have tried

```
self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Comment: then do some if else check before calling that animation and don't run it when u don't need...?

Comment: This is a case @Tj3n

Comment: @Tj3n Are you sure it called `self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()`?

Comment: Let set debug at self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()

Comment: I sure that self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations() have run @khuong291

Comment: Maybe self.view is not the view you want to cancel animation. You have to put those code correctly.

Comment: I believe that the best way in 2018 would be to use UIViewPropertyAnimator